# Clean way for a user to provide sets of LLVM instructions that I can parse in an LLVM Pass

Tags: c++, parsing, llvm, static-analysis

I'm using LLVM to perform static analysis using `opt` (i.e. an LLVM Pass). To perform this analysis, the user provides me with a text file that lists a few metrics and some stats about them. I'll need the user to also map each of these metrics to a set of LLVM instructions. Hence, the following could an example input file:

```
<name 1>.attribute_a = 12  
<name 2>.attribute_a = 11 
<name 3>.attribute_a = 0.6  

<name 1>.instructions = Alloca,Load,Fence  
<name 2>.instructions = ZExt,SExt  
<name 3>.instructions = Shl,Xor,Add,FAdd,Invoke
```

And so on. Parsing the attributes has already been taken care of and I have a map that points from the name of each metric to a struct of the data that pertains to it. What I'd like to do now is to parse the instructions and add the set of instructions to that struct of data.

I think it's most convenient for both the user and myself to have the instructions in the input file be represented as opcodes, so instead of the above we could have something like:

```
<name 1>.attribute_a = 12   

<name 1>.instructions = 26,27,30
```

But I'm not totally sure. What's the best way to represent the input data in a text file and what's the best way to actually parse the data once that's been done? I think I'll end up using something like `std::set<unsigned>` to represent the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it matters much as long as you have a 1-to-1 mapping between entities in your text file and actual LLVM IR instructions. The instruction names may be more readable, so you can parse into a `std::set<std::string>`. Note that `llvm::Instruction` has the method `getOpcodeName` which you can compare to a textual name read from a file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't actually use `llvm::Instruction`s with respect to this parsing, as strange as that may sound. I essentially parse before the pass, collect data during the pass, and use these results in some (hopefully) useful way after the pass. I already had things working with `int`s in the file but I like your idea of readability with `std::string` so I've done that. I do lots of comparisons with the strings though, so I'll likely end up converting the strings to ints anyway behind the scenes for efficiency.